# How to read Audio from Firebase,swift?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, xcode9.2

Here is my response:

```
Heritage Point1: [
  Audio: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweetwalk-192506.appspot.com/o/Heritage%20Point1%2FAudios%2Fsmstreet1.mp3?alt=media&token=a3224b55-6039-4c6f-ac4e-78b9cf818c89"
  CoverImage:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweetwalk-192506.appspot.com/o/Heritage%20Point1%2FImages%2Fsmstreet1.jpeg?alt=media&token=1acba6f0-8554-4b7e-828c-a7102c364d75"
  Description: "none of the above"
]
```

Used AVFoundation Framework. I'm using Firebase, Xcode 9.2, Swift 4

Anyone please help me to play Audio from Firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
let audioUrlStr = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweetwalk-192506.appspot.com/o/Heritage%20Point1%2FAudios%2Fsmstreet1.mp3?alt=media&token=a3224b55-6039-4c6f-ac4e-78b9cf818c89"
if let url = URL(string: audioUrlStr) {
   do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
      self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: Data(contentsOf: url))
      self.audioPlayer!.delegate = self
      self.audioPlayer!.volume = 2.0
      self.audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
      print("Audio ready to play")
      self.audioPlayer!.play()
   } catch let error {
        print("error occured while audio downloading")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```